# C++ TaskDialog windows seven style

Tags: c++, windows, icons, taskdialog

I'm working on the graph part of app, and I need to create a taskdialog box, to warn the user in case of he tries to move a file in a place where there is already this file, like this, on W7: (translation of the buttons: copy and replace, do not copy)

[image]

I used a CommandControl button, but I can only have this :

[image]

I don't know how to insert the icon and the file description in the Command button (if it is a commad button), and I have found nothing on the internet, perhaps because I search with the wrong therms!

Here is my code :

```
if (CTaskDialog::IsSupported())
{
     WCHAR const * pcwzHeading=L"My Heading";
    WCHAR const * pcwzTitle=L"My Title";

    WCHAR const * pcwzCollapsed=L"Collapsed Info";
    WCHAR const * pcwzExpanded=L"Expanded infos";
    WCHAR const * pcwzInfo=L"My Info to add";


              //Creation of the taskdialog
    CTaskDialog dia(pcwzContent, pcwzHeading,pcwzTitle,TDCBF_OK_BUTTON);


    dia.SetMainIcon(TD_INFORMATION_ICON);

            // Here there are my two commandbuttons
    dia.AddCommandControl(500,L"Copier et remplacer");
```

//( it is not this button i put a picture about, but a button i've created with the dialog creator //on visual studio, changing some parameters I can't access directly with code

```
    dia.AddCommandControl(501,L"Ne pas copier");
    dia.DoModal();
```